# How do I hide the header row in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I want to hide the header row from appearing, being visible on the table. (Both when viewed from desktop and mobile)

I tried:

```
"drawCallback":function(settings ){$("#mySelection thead").remove();} ,
```

While this code seems to render the table the way I want (header-less), it also effects the output of the buttons used here. The buttons are set to output whatever is visible (toggled by column visibility).

And unfortunately this code removes not just the theader in the export output, but also all the data that was in the tables.

The same thing happens when I try:

```
$("#mySelection thead").hide()
```

Is there anyway to keep the output as it was before and only hide the table headers from view, as in just the row with the column titles? I want to keep the buttons (copy, excel, pdf, colvis) working on the table data.

https://jsfiddle.net/287fum2q/

EDIT:

Using the following code in the CSS results in the problem I mentioned in the first part of my question:

```
.ui.table thead { display: none !important; }
```

As does this:

```
thead { display: none!important; }
```

If you could include a saved jsfiddle that shows the solution, that'd be all the more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the DataTables Jquery plugin may possibly have a bug. DataTables assumes the header display will not be set to `none`. When you set the header `display:none` it prevents the DataTables buttons from working as expected.

[Here's your workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/dolomike/bjqn2rtd/):

```
  .ui.table thead {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -9999px !important;
    left: -9999px !important;
  }
```

This removes the header from sight, but the DataTables buttons still have what they need to work correctly. I just learned this can be good practice (surprisingly) because `display:none` [makes content "inaccessible" to screen readers.](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)

Comment: I've tried that and it looks the same as before, could you include a saved jsfiddle?

Comment: I've [forked your fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/dolomike/bjqn2rtd/) If you already tried this, I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I see. If you compare the two, before and after the insertion of that code, you'll notice there's no change. The headers are "Company, Claims, Total Awarded". I know it doesn't look like your traditional table, Semantic UI makes the rows stack on top of each other to accommodate mobile view.

Comment: Ah I didn't look at it on mobile until just now. It worked on my PC. I'll come back and edit my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: @fly123 I've edited my answer. Please see my fiddle, I'm not encountering any issue with the data being removed from the tables.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it. But unfortunately on my end that jsfiddle still doesn't work. The headers are hidden but I am still getting empty outputs on all buttons presses. Others have said it works for them though. I'm beginning to think it's a device/browser compatibly issue. Thanks once again.

Comment: Okay, again I misunderstood the issue. But I think we're golden now! Check my updated answer/fiddle. And happy to help!

Comment: That is a clever trick. It does the job superbly. It both gets the headers out of sight yet maintains button functionality at the same time. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

`thead` css was conflict with `semanticui.min.css` so used `!important` to overwrite css

```
.ui.table thead {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Same here, this renders the output empty as stated before